# How can I show next birthday countdown in days, hours, and minutes?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to display days, hours, minutes until next birthday. I have calculated seconds, minutes, hours, and days. But I am getting the wrong value e.g.
"-1143988629855
-13241days -15hrs -38mins -10secs".

I want to show the countdown based on the birthday for e.g '05/06/1985'.
The below code works if the birthDates value is '05/06/2022', but i want to calculate using the value '05/06/1985'.

Can you please someone help?

```
//month day year
 const birthDates = new Date('05/06/1985')

 const second = 1000
 const minute = second * 60
 const hour = minute * 60
 const day = hour * 24
 let timerId

function countDown() {
   const tday = new Date()
   const timeSpan = birthDates - tday
   //milliseconds
   console.log(timeSpan)

   const days = Math.floor(timeSpan / day)
   const hours = Math.floor((timeSpan % day) / hour)
   const minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % hour) / minute)
   const seconds = Math.floor((timeSpan % minute) / second)

   console.log(days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'secs');
    }

   timerId = setInterval(countDown, second)
```

Comment: [`Date(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#timestamp_string): _"`dateString`: A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the `Date.parse()` method. (These formats are **IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps**, and also strings in a **version of ISO8601**.) "_

Comment: _"Note: **Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged** due to browser differences and inconsistencies."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the next birthday. You're checking how long ago you were born, not how long until the next birthday. By using a loop like: `while(date in past) { date.addYear() }`, we can get the desired functionality.

#### With continuous countdown to next birthday:

```js
 const birthDates = new Date('05/06/1985')

 const second = 1000
 const minute = second * 60
 const hour = minute * 60
 const day = hour * 24
 let timerId

function nextBirthday(birthdate) {
  let date = birthdate
  const timeSpan = date - new Date()
  while((date - new Date()) < 0) {
    date.setYear(1900 + date.getYear() + 1)
  }
  return date
}

function countDown() {
   const tday = new Date()
   const birthDate = nextBirthday(birthDates)
   const timeSpan = birthDate - tday
   //milliseconds

   const days = Math.floor(timeSpan / day)
   const hours = Math.floor((timeSpan % day) / hour)
   const minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % hour) / minute)
   const seconds = Math.floor((timeSpan % minute) / second)

   return (days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'secs');
}

function setCountdown() {
  document.querySelector('#countdown').innerHTML = countDown()
}

timerId = setInterval(setCountdown, second)
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

#### With a "Happy birthday" showing on your birthday:

```js
const birthDates = new Date('08/06/1985')

const second = 1000
const minute = second * 60
const hour = minute * 60
const day = hour * 24
let timerId

// date.toISOString() returns something like '2021-08-05T12:00:00.000Z'.

// We're just checking that the month and day are the same. 

// Note that this isn't very good at  timezones, so for me 
// it returned false for '08/05/1985' (which is today's date), but
// returned true for '08/06/1985', which is tomorrow. (Europe)
function sameDateAsToday(date) {
  return date.toISOString().substring(5,10) === (new Date()).toISOString().substring(5,10)
}

function nextBirthday(birthdate) {
  let date = birthdate
  const timeSpan = date - new Date()
  while((date - new Date()) < 0) {
    date.setYear(1900 + date.getYear() + 1)
  }
  return date
}

function countDown() {
  if(sameDateAsToday(birthDates)) {
    return 'HAPPY BIRTHDAY!'
  }

  const tday = new Date()
  const birthDate = nextBirthday(birthDates)
  const timeSpan = birthDate - tday
  //milliseconds

  const days = Math.floor(timeSpan / day)
  const hours = Math.floor((timeSpan % day) / hour)
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % hour) / minute)
  const seconds = Math.floor((timeSpan % minute) / second)

  return (days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'secs');
}

function setCountdown() {
  document.querySelector('#countdown').innerHTML = countDown()
}

timerId = setInterval(setCountdown, second)
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sebastian, that works fine now, however, if i want to show the Text Happy birthday!! on the Birthday day but the countdown on other days, how should I implement it on this code? Can you please help!!

Comment: @J.Lee I've edited my answer. See the second part, should work somewhat. However: If you're doing this on a professional project, I'd recommend that you try and use some sort of non-native Date-library (I reccommend Luxon) to handle differences in time. Javascript's built in Date is a little fickle when it comes down to the details.